# MCV C# web-service with POST and two variables

Tags: c#, web-services, model-view-controller

i am kinda new with the web services regarding to POST and i want to save the userId that i get from Owin and the id_cd in the favorite table. The webservice posted below is working however there is not need from me to get the return UserProvider back. The whole section ListAspNetUserLogins ... etc. is not needed but i can't seem to find a POST that allows me to add the two variables. What do i need to change to still have the two variables come in and get rid of the return UserProvider etc.

```
[Route("api/User/PostUserFavorite/{id_cd}/{UserId}")]
public async Task<List<AspNetUserLogins>> PostUserFavorite(int id_cd, string UserId)
{
    User_FavoriteCd newEntry = new User_FavoriteCd();
    newEntry.id_id = id_cd;
    newEntry.datetime = DateTime.Now;
    newEntry.UserId = UserId;
    db.User_FavoriteCd.Add(newEntry);
    db.SaveChanges();

    List<AspNetUserLogins> UserProvider = await db.AspNetUserLogins
    .Where(up => up.UserId == UserId)
    .ToListAsync();
    return UserProvider;
}
```

Comment: This is incredibly basic stuff, the method specifies that the return value is `Task<List<AspNetUserLogins>>`, change that to just `Task` to have no return value, or e.g. `Task<bool>` to have a `bool` return value. Then change the method body accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, that might be why it's so difficult to find information on it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not need a return value you can do:

```
[Route("api/User/PostUserFavorite/{id_cd}/{UserId}")]
public async Task PostUserFavorite(int id_cd, string UserId)
{
    User_FavoriteCd newEntry = new User_FavoriteCd();
    newEntry.id_id = id_cd;
    newEntry.datetime = DateTime.Now;
    newEntry.UserId = UserId;
    db.User_FavoriteCd.Add(newEntry);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: that was indeed simple, sometimes we might be thinking to difficult :-) VS2015 however told me to use void instead of the async Task part and works fine, just curious. How would i be able to prevent to add two times the same id_cd for the same userId in the table? Any good links perhaps that i could follow

Comment: @EwaldBos glad to help. (accept this as answer and upvote :)) I don't know if you have noticed that i have changed the last line too from `db.SaveChanges();` to `await db.SaveChangesAsync();` this should make it a Task. If you stay with your line `await db.SaveChangesAsync();` VS is right hence the is no return value. Regarding your question: I have no clue what `id_cd` is.